# What is the difference between $.pluginName and $.fn.pluginName

Tags: jquery

I see the following two patterns quite often. What is the difference between the two? When is each appropriate?

```
$.pluginName = function(){}
```

and

```
$.fn.pluginName = function(){}
```

Comment: asked lots of times.....possible duplicate of [jQuery Plugin Authoring: Why do some do jQuery.pluginName and others jQuery.fn.pluginName?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538043/jquery-plugin-authoring-why-do-some-do-jquery-pluginname-and-others-jquery-fn-pl)

Comment: @redsquare. Thanks for the link. I looked, but I couldn't find any similar questions.

Comment: This is basically asking the difference between `$` and `$.fn`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Plugin Authoring: Why do some do jQuery.pluginName and others jQuery.fn.pluginName?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538043/jquery-plugin-authoring-why-do-some-do-jquery-pluginname-and-others-jquery-fn-p)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Very simple:

`$.fn.pluginName` is a function callable on all `jQuery.init`* objects. This is useful for making chain-able functions to use with objects:

Example:

```
$.fn.foo = function(){...};

$('#bar').foo();
```

To continue chaining objects, you need to return another `jQuery.init` object (could be the original one, or a filtered one):

```
$.fn.foo = function(){ return this; };
```

---

`$.pluginName` is a function callable as `$.pluginName()`. This is useful for making utility functions, or storing a particular plugin's default states.

Example:

```
$.foo = function(){...};

bar = $.foo();
```

<sub>*The jQuery factory function (`jQuery()` or `$()`) actually returns a `new jQuery.init` object</sub>

Comment: Could you expand on what the Jquery.init object is?

Answer (score 2):

`$.pluginName` is for utility functions that have been added to the jQuery namespace, such as:

```
$.isArray();
$.extend();
etc
```

`$.fn.pluginName` is for functions that work on lists of elements as returned by the jQuery `$(...)` function:

```
$(...).attr( ... );
$(...).first( ... );
etc
```